# Find Resources a GCP service account is tied to within a project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, service-accounts

I am doing a quick inventory of our service accounts within a particular GCP project and I want to find all the resources a specific service account has access to. This seems like it'd be a simple lookup, since a GCP policy is simply an `Identity` given a `role` on a particular `resouce`, however it doesn't seem like `gcloud` has this specific lookup... unless I'm missing something. I can find the service account/role combination via IAM or  `gcloud beta asset search-all-iam-policies` but the final portion of the query seems to be missing.

Answer (score 1):

To find all the resources authorized for a specific account, using the Cloud Asset Inventory is the good tool.

You can perform this kind of request

```
gcloud beta asset search-all-iam-policies  \
    --scope=<Where to search> 
    --query="policy:<who to search>"
```

The scope is in which perimeter you are looking for. It can be

- `organizations/<OrganisationNumber>`
- `folders/<folderNumber>`
- `projects/<ProjectNumber or ProjectID>`

The query is what you search. Here a policy with a specific service account email. So, set it and launch the request.

Does it what you are looking for?

Comment: These two documents [1][2] provides further details on this which can be used for reference. [1] https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/asset/search-all-iam-policies [2] https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-iam-policies#how_to_construct_a_query